# Creating a custom filter for fail2ban

Tags: linux, linux-networking, fail2ban

I'm trying to create a custom jail and filter in fail2ban for motion stream http authentication. The log directory is `/var/log/motion/motion.log` and a failed login attempt generates:

```
[0:ml1] [ALR] [STR] [Nov 02 16:47:57] handle_basic_auth: motion-stream - failed auth attempt from 192.168.0.65
```

My custom jail in `/etc/failban/jail.local` looks like this:

```
[motion-auth]

enabled = true
port     = 8010
filter = motion-auth.conf
logpath  = /var/log/motion/motion.log
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
maxretry = 3
findtime = 10800
bantime = 259200
```

And my `motion-auth.conf` file in `/etc/failban/filter.d/` looks like this:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf
[Definition]
_pref_line = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+)?
failregex = [0:ml1] [ALR] [STR] .* handle_basic_auth: motion-stream - failed auth attempt from <HOST>
```

I'm having trouble writing the failregex in the filter file. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Have you used the `fail2ban-regex` command so you can iteratively test as you make changes? Also `[` have meaning in regex's you will probably need to escape them with a leading `\`

Comment: That should be with a leading \

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it still appears in search engine results, so here's a detailed answer.

For regular expressions, `[ALR]` and similar bracketed character strings have a special meaning, namely: "one of the following characters: A, L or R". To tell the regex that you want to match the literal characters `[` and `]`, escape them with `\` backslash characters.

```bash
log_line="[0:ml1] [ALR] [STR] [Nov 02 16:47:57] \
handle_basic_auth: motion-stream - failed auth attempt from 192.168.0.65"
regex="\[0:ml1\] \[ALR\] \[STR\] .* handle_basic_auth: motion-stream - \
failed auth attempt from <HOST>"
fail2ban-regex "$log_line" "$regex" | grep matched
Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 1 matched, 0 missed
```